# selector bootstrap con variable ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

soy nuevo en esto de la programación web, estoy realizando unas practicas y estoy algo atascado. 
A parte de no haber usado nunca este tipo de lenguajes trabajo con el código heredado de otra persona con la cuál no tengo posibilidad de contactar. Basándome en la estructuración de todo el código he conseguido crear esta función ajax que me devuelve una lista de objectos estilo:
[Objeto1, DefObjeto1]
[Objeto2, DefObjeto2]
...

Esta lista necesitaría usarla como posibles objetos de selección en un desplegable que está definido en el mismo documento "historial.js"

función ajax

```
var sel = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
  //function to load different types of pices     
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/public/index.php/tipusDePesaTots',   //url local
      type : "POST",
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        sel = result;
        //alert(sel.toSource());  
      },
      error: function(result){
        alert(sel);
      }
  })
  return sel;
});
```

creación del formulario con el selector:

```
function mostraDialeg(pesaActual, usuari){
    alert(sel.toSource());
    //Get piece's number and year
    if (pesaActual.length == 14) {
        var posicioPesaSubs = pesaActual.substring(6, 7);
        var anyPesaSubs = pesaActual.substring(10);
    } else {
        var posicioPesaSubs = pesaActual.substring(6, 8);
        var anyPesaSubs = pesaActual.substring(11);
    }
        //Comprobació
        //console.log('Peça: ' + posicioPesaSubs + ' Any: ' + anyPesaSubs + ' Usuari: ' + usuari);

    quadre = '<div id="qDialeg" class="modal fade">';
    quadre += '<div class="modal-dialog">';
    quadre += '<div class="modal-content">';
    quadre += '<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
    quadre += '<div class="modal-body">';
  quadre += '<form class="form-horizontal">';
    quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="etiqueta">Etiqueta:</label>';
    quadre += '<input type="text" name="etiqueta" id="etiqueta" size="50" value=""/> </div>';
  quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="tipusP">Tipus:</label>';
    quadre += '<select name="tipusP" id="tipusP"><option value="sel">$sel</option>';    
    quadre += '</select></div>';
    quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="aplicat">Aplicat a:</label>';
    quadre += '<input type="text" name="aplicat" id="aplicat" size="50" value=""/></div>';
    quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="compromis">Compromis:</label>';
    quadre += '<input type="text" name="compromis" id="compromis" size="50" value=""/></div>';
    quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="acompliment">Acompliment (%):</label>';
    quadre += '<input type="text" name="acompliment" id="acompliment" value=""/></div>';
    quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="validacio">Validació:</label>';
    quadre += '<select name="validacio" id="validacio"><option value="PRA">Pra</option><option value="DIR">Dir</option></select>';
    quadre += '<input type="checkbox" name="validat" id="validat" value="1"/></div>';
    quadre += '<div class="camps"><label for="comments">Altres:</label>';
    quadre += '<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea></div>';
    quadre += '<a id="okPesa"></a>';
    quadre += '<a href="" class="btn btn-primary botoDialeg">Cancel</a>';
    quadre += '<a id="modifica"></a>';
    quadre += '</form></div></div></div></div></div>';
```

El selector es el tipusP,

me encuentro con un par de problemas, el primero y principal es que no consigo capturar el valor de sel fuera de la función ajax, me sale que sel no está definido y en segundo lugar no estoy seguro de como definir el selector del formulario para que coja los valores de la variable.

Alguien puede arrojar un poco de luz al tema?

Saludos y perdón porqué posiblemente la pregunta, puede que no resulte muy compleja con algo de práctica, pero como digo no he usado nunca estos lenguajes y me está costando encontrar la solución.

EDIT: perdonad mi ignorancia, creo que murphy ha entrado en acción, he conseguido capturar la variable sel, simplemente la he declarado fuera de la función $(document).ready(function(){ y no solamente fuera de la función ajax como lo tenía. Ahora voy a seguir intentando pasar la variable para el selector, he modificado el código al que me funciona por ahora.

Comment: En qué momento llamas a `mostraDialeg`? Primero tienes que capturar el valor de `sel ` (con el ajax) y luego dibujar el contenido del selector. En tu construcción de `quadre` aparece como `$sel` que no está definido. Muéstranos qué haces con `quadre` una vez que terminas de construir toda esa cadena. ¿Qué valor tiene la respuesta del ajax dentro del `success`?

Comment: Acabo de conseguir lo que necesitava así que ya está, aún así gracias por ofrecerte, me faltava crear un bucle for en la zona de las opciones para que capturase todas las opciones.